# How to remove .NET Framework 4.5 Beta

Tags: .net-framework, .net-4.5

How can you remove .NET Framework 4.5 Beta (either manually or using a cleanup tool)?

Comment: according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx You have to remove Dot Net 4.5 from control panel that removes .net 4 also and you have to reinstall 4 again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the framework installs new assemblies into the Global Assembly Cache and other locations within your *Windows* directory I would advise against a manual uninstallation. Why can you not uninstall via the proper channels in *Programs and Features*?

Note that .net 4.5 essentially overwrites any previous .net 4.0 installation. So once you remove it you will have to reinstall .net 4.0

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat.  Had uninstalled and got something messed up, so I repaired 4.5 and did the Programs and Features uninstall and all was good.